# Renaming the XML file with phrase included inside the XML

Tags: xml, vba, tree, rename

Dears,

I have a macro that is saving XML attachments from various e-mails into the folder on computer. The XMLs are named with "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss XYZ"
I would like to create macro, that would change the name from all XMLs archived in given folder. The name would have to be taken from the phrase hidden inside XML file as per below example. So each XML would have individual name taken from phrase hidden in XML.

Could you please advise what is the best way to do it? Is it possible?

[image]

Could you please advise how to make above happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use a power shell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$path = 'c:\temp\*.xml'
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $path
foreach($xml in $xmlFiles.FullName)
{
   $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($xml)
   $code = $doc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq 'AdministrativeReferenceCode'})[0].Value
   $code = $code.Trim()
   Write-Host $code 
   if($code.Length -gt 0) {ren $xml $code}
}
```

Comment: Hello
The script works and files are renamed, but the original XML files have lost their extension. Any advice on that?

I owe you a beer, thank you!

Comment: use {ren $xml $code.xml}

Comment: I have changed this  if($code.Length -gt 0) {ren $xml $code}, into: if($code.Length -gt 0) {ren $xml $code.xml}

Now the script is not working and shows error

Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.
At C:\1 char:37
+    if($code.Length -gt 0) {ren $xml $code.xml}
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemC
   ommand

Comment: Are you trying to fix the files with no extensions or rerunning the script with original files names?

Comment: Rerunning the script with original file names

Comment: Then try {ren $xml ($code + '.xml') }

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! 
If you will be anywhere close to Silesia region in Poland - I owe you a good craft beer :-) Just let me know :-)

Have a nice day

Comment: I'm 4,000 miles away.

Comment: Hey jdweng, 

I would have one more question.  After using the powershell script, my xml's are renamed, but when I open my VBA makro from outlook - outlook will save old XML's with original filename (this cause that I would have two same XML's but with different filename). Then when I open your script - I got error, that the file cannot be renamed, because the filename already exist. 

Is it possible to revise your script in the way, that: 
"in case if new filename (AdministrativeReferenceCode) exist - overwrite the file"?

Comment: Use move-item instead of ren : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @DamianD: If this answers your question, please "accept" this answer.

Comment: Hello FunThomas,

I'm not sure if i will handle this FAQ about move-item from jdweng, but I do not want to push the line, you already helped me a lot guys (special thanks to Mr jdweng). I accept of course his answer, not sure if I should close my question somewhere additionally? 

have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Dears, the final working code is as provided by Mr. jdweng from comment section

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$path = 'c:\temp\*.xml'
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $path
foreach($xml in $xmlFiles.FullName)
{
   $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($xml)
   $code = $doc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq 'AdministrativeReferenceCode'})[0].Value
   $code = $code.Trim()
   Write-Host $code 
   if($code.Length -gt 0) {ren $xml ($code + '.xml')}
}
```